# Android Gradle error while using environment variables

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using the below code in my gradle file to fetch a username and password which I have added in the environment variables of my computer.

```
def uname = System.getenv("USERNAME")
def pwd = System.getenv("PASSWORD")
buildConfigField "String", "USERNAME", uname
buildConfigField "String", "PASSWORD", pwd
```

It gives me the error shown in screenshot while I try to run the app. This is a screenshot from BuildConfig.java auto generated file. It shows, the username and password is being picked up correctly by gradle, but a syntax error while using it? I am posting the error message screenshot. Is there a problem defining and using variable this way in gradle? Any help to resolve this is much appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BuildConfig file is missing quotes around those strings.  Try this in your `build.gradle` instead:

```
buildConfigField "String", "USERNAME", '"' + uname + '"'
buildConfigField "String", "PASSWORD", '"' + pwd + '"'
```